# Using GSON for multiple java object models

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, gson

GSON library is used to parse JSON objects and save directly into the models.
It's make it very easy and efficient to use GSON but how can we use GSON in cases where we have to use only certain keys of the JSON object or how can use GSON to save different models requiring different keys without parsing each element from the JSON ( which is the whole point of using GSON )

Let's say we have a JSON J1 = {"k1":"v1" , "k2":"v2"} . Now i want to save k1 pair in model m1 and k2 pair in model m2. Is there anyway i can achieve this through GSON without parsing JSON object

Comment: More information is needed. Do you want to parse a JSON object with the two String members k1 and k2? Cause if thats the case then you only need to create a POJO with two String members named k1 and k2 and supply it to the GSON decoder.

Comment: What is your aversion to parsing JSON?

Comment: just don't declare `k2` field in `m1`, and `k1` field in `m2`. This way it will ignore every JSON value, that has no field for it,.